# Парсинг строки в си

Tags: c, строки, парсер

Как максимально эффективно вытащить данные из строки? Имеется на входе:

```
" { 'Parametr1 2000' ; [ 5 & 2 ] ; [ 3 & 2 ] }{'ParametrLoooooooong 2021';[10&5];[ 6 &4]}"
"{'Parametr 2000' ; [ 5&2 ] ; [ 3 & 4 ] }"
"{ 'Parametr 2000';[ 5 & 2 ];[ 3 &10 ] }"
```

нужно:

1. вытащить названия параметра в одинарных ковычках
2. вытащить пары двух чисел в [ ] скобках, разделенные символом &

Хочу на выходе получить:

```
str 1 - Parametr1 2000 5 2 3 2
str 2 - ParametrLoooooooong 2021 10 5 6 4
str 3 - Parametr 2000 5 2 3 4
str 4 - Parametr 2000 5 2 3 10
```

Изначально планировал тремя ссканфами обойтись(на название параметра, на первцю пару чисел, на вторую), но не понимаю как из первого входа вытащить две строки(str 1 и str 2). Если кто-то поможет кодом, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Максимально эффективно? Значит ли это, что не нужно смотреть на наличие скобок, корректность?

Comment: попробуйте поискать какую нибудь библиотеку регулярных выражений для `c` или можете сделать свой конечный автомат чтобы такие строчки парсить

Comment: Если опыта в написании парсеров нет, и нет особого желания его получать, то нужно юзать библиботеки. В `C++` это легко сделать с помощью `std::regex`, `std::regex_match`, `std::regex_search`.

Answer (score 4):

Что-то типа такого устроит?...

```
void getData(const char * s_)
{
    char * s = _strdup(s_); // Чтоб можно было strtok пользовать
    for(char * c = strtok(s,"}"); c; c = strtok(NULL,"}"))
    {
        char s1[128]; int a[4];
        sscanf(c,"%*[^']'%[^']%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d",s1,&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3]);
        printf("%s %d %d %d %d\n",s1,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
    }
    free(s);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const char * s[] = {
        " { 'Parametr1 2000' ; [ 5 & 2 ] ; [ 3 & 2 ] }{'ParametrLoooooooong 2021';[10&5];[ 6 &4]}",
        "{'Parametr 2000' ; [ 5&2 ] ; [ 3 & 4 ] }",
        "{ 'Parametr 2000';[ 5 & 2 ];[ 3 &10 ] }"
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); ++i)
        getData(s[i]);

}
```

Comment: Абсолютно unmaintainable sscanf. Я бы парсил этот формат данных по скобкам, кавычкам и прочим разделителям (читая getchar-ом). Ну а числа вместе с пробелами,  можно простым sscanf-ом выбирать

Comment: Согласен с @avp, может может заюзать ссканф со сканфом и двигать указатели, но не совсем представляю как бы это выглядело, я ограничен в использовании _strdup

Comment: @avp мб поделишься решением, есл не сложно? Уж слишком большой интерес возник к твоему варианту решения

Comment: @deniskalistrat, сегодня вряд ли (если только совсем уже ночью опять залезу в ruSO)

Comment: @avp Или написать regexp на С :) Мне кажется, что при изменении паттерна строки любой код окажется не слишком поддерживаемым. Тут хоть менять надо будет только одну форматную строку.

Comment: @Mikhailo, для большинства реальных программ regexp-ы (кроме либо очевидных, либо канонических, кстати, в Си regexps, есть, см. например, man regcomp) это вообще плохо.

Answer (score 2):

Скорей всего последняя правка ответа.

Алгоритм ниже (по моим небольшим тестам) парсит строчку в массив по строгим правилам. Единственный минус алгоритма, который я на данный момент нашел - это то, что он парсит только целые числа, но если изменить функцию `isNumber` и использовать не `atoi`, то можно и под вещественные переписать.

В общем вот алгоритм:

Функция `main`:

```
char* str = (char*)" { 'Parametr1 2000' ; [ 5 & 2 ] ; [ 3 & 2 ] }{ 'ParametrLoooooooong 2021';[10&5];[ 6 &4]}";
Param params[10];
int count = 0;
char* s = str;

do{
    s = strchr(s, '{');
    if (s == NULL) break;

    char* temp = getParam(s, params[count]);

    if (temp != NULL) {
        printf("str %d - %s %d %d %d %d\n", count + 1, params[count]);
        ++count;
    }
    else
        printf("Error str\n");
    ++s;
} while (s != NULL);
```

Структура `Param`:

```
struct Param {
    char* name;
    int a1;
    int b1;
    int a2;
    int b2;
};
```

Функция `getParam`:

```
char* getParam(char* str, Param& par) {
    char* s = isNextSymb(str, '{');
    if (s != NULL) {
        s = getNameParam(str + 1, par.name);
        if (s != NULL) {
            s = isNextSymb(s + 1, ';');
            if (s != NULL) {
                s = getDataParam(s + 1, par.a1, par.b1);
                if (s != NULL) {
                    s = isNextSymb(s + 1, ';');
                    if (s != NULL) {
                        s = getDataParam(s + 1, par.a2, par.b2);
                        if (s != NULL)
                            return (s = isNextSymb(s + 1, '}'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Ну и дальше я просто все остальные функции выложу:

```
char* skipSpaces(char* str) {
    while (*str != '\0' && *str == ' ') ++str;
    return str;
}

char* isNextSymb(char* str, const char symb) {
    str = skipSpaces(str);
    if(*str == symb)
        return str;
    return NULL;
}

char* getNameParam(char* str, char*& out_str) {
    char* s = isNextSymb(str, '\'');

    if (s != NULL) {
        ++s;
        char* temp = strchr(s, '\'');
        if (temp == NULL) return NULL;
        out_str = (char*)malloc(temp - s + 1);
        char* n = out_str;
        while (*s != '\0' && *s != '\'') {
            *n = *s;
            ++n;
            ++s;
        }

        if (*s == '\0')
            s = NULL;

        *n = '\0';
    }

    return s;
}

char* isNumber(char* str) {
    str = skipSpaces(str);
    if (*str == '-') ++str;
    str = skipSpaces(str);
    while (*str != '\0' && *str >= '0' && *str <= '9') ++str;
    if (*str == '\0') return NULL;
    return str;
}

char* getDataParam(char* str, int& a, int& b) {
    char* s = isNextSymb(str, '[');
    if (s != NULL) {
        a = atoi(s + 1);
        s = isNumber(s + 1);
        if (s != NULL) {
            s = isNextSymb(s, '&');
            if (s != NULL) {
                b = atoi(s + 1);
                s = isNumber(s + 1);
                if (s != NULL)
                    return (s = isNextSymb(s, ']'));
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Вот ссылка на [код](https://ideone.com/ahzESg). Сразу хочу извинится, что код по ссылке на `c++`. Я не смог на этом сайте, запустить без ошибок на `си`.

Если хотите, чтобы я объяснил код, то отпишите в комментарии. Удачи :)

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант, c проверкой синтаксиса, пробелы пропускаются:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *cur = NULL;
char text[256];

void skip_spaces() {
    while (*cur == ' ') ++cur;
}

void ex(char c) { // expect char
    skip_spaces();
    
    if (*cur != c) {
        printf("\nError: expected '%c' but not '%c'\n", c, *cur);
        exit(-1);
    }
    ++cur;
}

void str() { // string
    ex('\'');
    char* tp = text;
    while(*cur != '\'' && *cur != '\0') {
        *tp++ = *cur++;
    }
    *tp = '\0';
    ex('\'');

    printf("%s ", text);
}

void num() { // number
    skip_spaces();

    char* tp = text;
    while(*cur >= '0' && *cur <= '9') {
        *tp++ = *cur++;
    }
    *tp = '\0';

    if (tp == text) {
        printf("\nError: expected number but not '%c'\n", *cur);
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("%s ", text);
}

void two_p() { // two parameters
    ex('['); num(); ex('&'); num(); ex(']');
}

int record = 0;
void parse_data(const char* s) {
    cur = (char*) s;
    while(*cur != '\0') {
        printf("str %d - ", ++record);
        ex('{'); str(); ex(';'); two_p(); ex(';'); two_p(); ex('}');
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    const char * s[] = {
        " { 'Parametr1 2000' ; [ 5 & 2 ] ; [ 3 & 2 ] }{'ParametrLoooooooong 2021';[10&5];[ 6 &4]}",
        "{'Parametr 2000' ; [ 5&2 ] ; [ 3 & 4 ] }",
        "{ 'Parametr 2000';[ 5 & 2 ];[ 3 &10 ] }"
    };

    char ** sp = (char**) s;
    char ** end = sp + sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);
    for(; sp != end; ++sp) {
        parse_data(*sp);
    }
    
}
```

**UPDATE**

Добавил генерацию дерева AST из описания грамматики (облегченная EBNF), неоптимально, но работает. Память не чистил.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define ENTRIES 128
void handler_func(int index, char *s , int size); 

char *cur = NULL;
    
typedef struct node {
    enum node_type {TERM, NON_TERM, PARAM, OR, AND, REPEAT, DIGIT, LETTER} type;
    char value; // for TERM 
    char* id;   // for NON_TERM
    int param_value; // for PARAM
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
} Node;

struct st_entry {
    char* name;
    Node* node;
};

struct st_entry st[ENTRIES] = {0};
int st_last_index = 0;

struct st_entry* find_entry(char *name) {
    for (int j = 0; j < st_last_index; ++j) {
        char* p = st[j].name;
        char* ii = name;
        // find entry by name
        while (*p == *ii && *p != '\0')  {
            ++p;
            ++ii;
        }
        
        if (*p == '\0' && *ii == *p) {
            return &st[j];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

struct st_entry* add_entry(char* name, Node* node) {
    st[st_last_index].name = name;
    st[st_last_index].node = node;
    return &st[st_last_index++];
}

int st_num_param(char* name) {
    char *p = "%";
    char *n = name;
    while (*p == *n && *p != '\0') {
        ++p;
        ++n;
    }
    if (*p != '\0') return -1;

    return atoi(n);
}

void skip_spaces() {
    while (*cur == ' ' || *cur == '\n') ++cur;
}

void ex(char c) { // expect char
    skip_spaces();
    
    if (*cur != c) {
        printf("\nError: expected '%c' but not '%c'\n", c, *cur);
        exit(-1);
    }
    ++cur;
}

char* id() { // identificator
    skip_spaces();

    char* p = cur;
    while (*cur != ' ' && *cur != '\0' && *cur != '}' && *cur != '|' && *cur != ';') {
        ++cur;
    }
    unsigned int size = cur - p;
    char* ret = malloc(size + 1);
    char *pret = ret;
    for(unsigned int i = size; i != 0; --i) {
         *pret++ = *p++;
    }

    pret = '\0';
    return ret; 
}

Node* expr() {
    //enum node_type operation = AND;
    skip_spaces();

    Node* pnode = NULL;

    while (*cur != '\0' && *cur != ';') { 
        //printf("operation = %d\n", operation);
        if (*cur == '\'') {
            // terminal
            ++cur;
            char c = *cur;
            if (c == '\0') {
                printf("Error: expected a char\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
            ++cur;

            //printf("terminal = '%c'\n", c);

            Node* term = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            term->value = c; 
            //if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            //  term->type = DIGIT;         
            //} else {
                term->type = TERM;          
            //}
            ex('\'');

            if (pnode) {
                Node* anode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                anode->type = AND;
                anode->left = pnode;
                anode->right = term;
                pnode = anode;
            } else {
                pnode = term;
            }
            skip_spaces();

        } else if (*cur == '|') {
            ++cur;
            Node* n = expr();
            if (pnode) {
                Node* anode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                anode->type = OR;
                anode->left = pnode;
                anode->right = n;
                pnode = anode;
            } else {
                pnode = n;
            }
            skip_spaces();
            
        } else if (*cur == '(') {
             
        } else if (*cur == ')') {

        } else if (*cur == '{') {
            ++cur;
            Node* n = expr();

            Node* rep = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            rep->type = REPEAT;
            rep->left = n;
            rep->right = NULL;

            if (pnode) {
                Node* anode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                anode->type = AND;
                anode->left = pnode;
                anode->right = rep;
            } else {
                pnode = rep;
            }

        } else if (*cur == '}') {
            ++cur;
            skip_spaces();
            return pnode;
        } else if (*cur == ' ') {
            printf("SPACE HERE");
            skip_spaces();
        } else {
            // non-terminal

            char* name = id();
//              printf("non-terminal = %s\n", name);
            // search in symbol_table
            struct st_entry * entry = find_entry(name);

            if (entry) {
                free(name);
            } else {
                // add in table
//                  printf("add in table: %s\n", name);
                Node* anode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                anode->type = NON_TERM;
                anode->id = name;
                anode->left = NULL;
                anode->right = NULL;

                entry = add_entry(name, anode);

                int num = st_num_param(name);

                if (num != -1) {
                    entry->node->type = PARAM;
                    entry->node->param_value = num;
                }
            }
            
            if (pnode) {
                Node* anode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                anode->type = AND;//operation;
                anode->left = pnode;
                anode->right = entry->node;

                pnode = anode;
            } else {
                pnode = entry->node;
            }
            skip_spaces();
        }

    }
    return pnode;
}

Node* parse_grammar(const char * grammar) {
    cur = grammar;

    while(*cur != '\0') {
        char* record = id();
//      printf("%s\n", record);
        
        struct st_entry* root_entry = find_entry(record);

        if (!root_entry) {
            Node* anode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            anode->type = NON_TERM;
            anode->id = record;
            anode->left = NULL;
            anode->right = NULL;

            root_entry = add_entry(record, anode);
        }

        ex('=');

        Node* pnode = expr();
        if(root_entry->node->type == NON_TERM) {
            Node* p = root_entry->node;
            p->type = pnode->type;
            p->left = pnode->left;
            p->right = pnode->right;
            p->id = pnode->id;
            p->param_value = pnode->param_value;
            p->value = pnode->value;
            free(pnode);
        } else {
            root_entry->node->left = pnode;
        }
        if (*cur == ';') ++cur;
        skip_spaces();
    }

    struct st_entry* entry = find_entry("digit");
    if (entry && entry->node->type == NON_TERM) {
        // set "digit" to default if there is no NON_TERMINAL "digit"
        // NON_TERM node shouldn't be presented in the end of creating of grammar AST
        Node* p = entry->node;
        p->type = DIGIT;
    }

    entry = find_entry("letter");
    if (entry && entry->node->type == NON_TERM) {
        // set "letter" to default if there is no NON_TERMINAL "letter"
        // NON_TERM node shouldn't be presented in the end of creating of grammar AST
        Node* p = entry->node;
        p->type = LETTER;
    }

    return st[0].node;
}


bool visit(Node* node) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        printf("Node is NULL\n");
        return false;
    }

    switch(node->type) {
        case TERM:
            skip_spaces();

            if (node->value == *cur) {
                printf("term=%c\n", *cur);
                //printf("equal\n");
                ++cur;
                return true;
            } 
            //printf("Expected '%c' but not '%c'\n", node->value, *cur);
            return false;
            break;

        /*
        case NON_TERM:
            printf("NON TERMINAL: %s\n", node->id);
            return visit(node->left);
            break;
        //*/
        case LETTER : {
            //printf("visit LETTER: %c\n", *cur);
            if ( (*cur >= 'a' && *cur <= 'z') || (*cur >= 'A' && *cur <= 'Z') ) {
                printf("LETTER: %c\n", *cur);
                ++cur;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }   break;

        case DIGIT : {
            //skip_spaces();
            //printf("visit DIGIT: %c\n", *cur);
            if (*cur >= '0' && *cur <= '9') {
                printf("DIGIT: %c\n", *cur);
                ++cur;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
            break;

        case REPEAT: {
            //printf("REPEAT: %s\n", "g");
            char* tmp = cur;    
            while(visit(node->left)) {
                tmp = cur;
            }
            cur = tmp;
            //printf("REPEAT end: %c\n", *cur);
            return true;
        }
            break;

        case PARAM:
            skip_spaces();
            //printf("PARAM: %s\n", node->id);
            {
                // remember string
                char* begin_visit = cur;
                bool r = visit(node->left);
                int diff = (int)(cur - begin_visit);
                handler_func(node->param_value, begin_visit, diff);
                return r;
            }
            break;

        case AND: {
            skip_spaces();
            //printf("AND\n");
            bool a = visit(node->left);
            if (a == false) return a;
            //printf("AND: a = %d\n", a);
            bool b = visit(node->right);
            //printf("AND: b = %d\n", b);
            return a && b;
        }
            break;

        case OR: {
            skip_spaces();
            //printf("OR\n");
            //printf("OR cur = %c\n", *cur);
            char* tmp = cur;    
            bool a = visit(node->left);
            //printf("OR a cur = %c\n", *cur);
            //printf("OR: a = %d\n", a);
            if (a) return true;
            cur = tmp;
            bool b = visit(node->right);
            //printf("OR b cur = %c\n", *cur);
            //printf("OR: b = %d\n", b);
            return b;
        }
            break;

        default:
            // error
            printf("Error: wrong node type\n");
            exit(-1);
            break;
    }

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct record {
    char* name;
    int param[4];
};

struct record* precord = NULL;
struct record records[256];
int records_last_index = 0;
int current_param_index = 0;


void param0(char* s, int size) {
    //printf("param0 executed\nstr=");
    char* name = malloc(size + 1);
    char* n = name;
    while(size != 0) {
        *n++ = *s;
        //printf("%c", *s);
        ++s;
        --size;
    }
    //printf("\n");
    *n = '\0';
    records[records_last_index].name = name;
}

void param1(char* s, int size) {
    int r = atoi(s);
    records[records_last_index].param[current_param_index++] = r;
}

void dummy_func(char* s, int size) {
    printf("DUMMY FUNCTION executed\nstr=");
    while(size != 0) {
        printf("%c", *s++);
        --size;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void empty_func(char* s, int size) {
    
}

#define HANDLERS_SIZE 16
void (*handlers[HANDLERS_SIZE])(char *s , int size);

void init_handlers() {
    handlers[0] = param0;
    handlers[1] = param1;

    for(int i = 2; i < HANDLERS_SIZE; ++i) {
        handlers[i] = empty_func;
        //handlers[i] = dummy_func;
    }
}

void handler_func(int index, char *s , int size) {
    handlers[index](s, size);
}

void parse_data(Node* gram, const char* s) {
    cur = s;
    while(*cur != '\0') {
        bool result = visit(gram);
        //printf("PARSE_DATA result = %d\n", result);
        current_param_index = 0;    
        if (result) {
            // make record
            ++records_last_index;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    const char *grammar = 
        "record = '{' pstring ';' two_param ';' two_param '}' ;"
        "pstring = ''' %0 ''' ;"
        "%0 = {char} ;"
        "char = letter | ' ' | digit ;"
        "two_param = '[' %1 '&' %1 ']' ;"
        "%1 = {digit} ;"
    ;
    // "digit" is by default
    // "letter" is by default

    Node* gram = parse_grammar(grammar);    

    //*
    printf("\nentries:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < st_last_index; ++i) {
        printf("entry: %s\n", st[i].name);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //*/

    init_handlers();

    const char * s[] = {
        " { 'Parametr1 2001' ; [ 5 & 2 ] ; [ 3 & 2 ] }{'ParametrLoooooooong 2021';[10&5];[ 6 &4]}",
        "{'Parametr 2002' ; [ 5&2 ] ; [ 3 & 4 ] }",
        "{ 'Parametr 2003';[ 5 & 2 ];[ 3 &10 ] }"
    };

    char ** sp = (char**) s;
    char ** end = sp + sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);
    for(; sp != end; ++sp) {
        parse_data(gram, *sp);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < records_last_index; ++i) {
        printf("str %d = %s %d %d %d %d\n", i, records[i].name, records[i].param[0], records[i].param[1], records[i].param[2], records[i].param[3]);
    }
}
```

[github](https://github.com/tigertv/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/ru-parser-string-in-c-1226489)

Answer (score 2):

Как обычно и бывает, более-менее подробный разбор с анализом ошибок и попытками продолжить работу после них выливается в достаточно длинную программу.

Хотя, основная функция разбора довольно компактна и легко перестаиваема под небольшие изменения формата данных.

```
// структура для разобранного фрагмента данных вида:
// { 'name of data' ; [1 & 2]; [3 & 4] } { ... } ... 
struct dfr {
  const char *fr_begin;
  size_t fr_len;
  const char *name;
  size_t namelen;
  int p1[2],
    p2[2];
  int str_error;
};

// returns data fragment length or 0 (if no more in str)
size_t
get_data_fragment (const char *str, struct dfr *p)
{
  p->str_error = 0;
  p->fr_len = 0;
  // пропустим разделители до `{`
  p->fr_begin = strspn(str, " \t\n\r") + str;
  if (*(p->fr_begin) != '{') {
    if (*(p->fr_begin)) // неверный символ разделитель 
      p->str_error = NO_FR_BEGIN;
    return 0;           // конец данных в строке ?
  }

  const char *scont = get_data_name(p->fr_begin + 1, p);
  if (!scont)
    return locate_fragment_end(str, &p->str_error);

  // достаточно очевидный `sscanf()` для выборки числовой части данных
  char c = 0;
  int nchrs = 0,
      rc = sscanf(scont, " ; [ %d & %d ] ; [ %d & %d %c%n",
                  p->p1, p->p1 + 1, p->p2, p->p2 + 1, &c, &nchrs);
  if (rc != 5 || c != ']') {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid data pair(s) scanf = %d in: \"...", rc);
    while (*scont && *scont != '}')
      fputc(*scont++, stderr);
    fputs("...\"\n", stderr);
    p->str_error = INVALID_DATA;
  }

  size_t sz_ret = locate_fragment_end(scont + nchrs, &p->str_error);

  if (sz_ret) {
    p->fr_len = sz_ret + (scont + nchrs - p->fr_begin);
    return p->fr_len + (p->fr_begin[p->fr_len] != 0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Эта функция вот так вызывается в цикле для обработки всех фрагментов данных в одной строке

```
for (char *str = data[i]; str && (l = get_data_fragment(str, &r)); str += l) {
  if (r.str_error)
    fprintf(stderr, "weak str_error %d\n", r.str_error);

  print_fr_str(&r, ++n);
}
```

При выходе из цикла по получению в `r.str_error` кода `NO_FR_BEGIN` (т.е. при поиске начала фрагмента данных найден неверный символ-разделитель) можно попробовать найти начало фрагмента, вызвав `str = strchr(str, '{');` (я не стал загромождать пример (и так, довольно "увесистый") подобными способами восстановления обработки после найденных ошибок).

Весь код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// структура для разобранного фрагмента данных вида:
// { 'name of data' ; [1 & 2]; [3 & 4] } { ... } ... 
struct dfr {
  const char *fr_begin;
  size_t fr_len;
  const char *name;
  size_t namelen;
  int p1[2],
    p2[2];
  int str_error;
};

#define NO_FR_BEGIN       (1 << 0)
#define NO_FR_END         (1 << 1)
#define NO_NAME_SQUOTE    (1 << 2)
#define NO_NAME_EQUOTE    (1 << 3)
#define INVALID_DATA      (1 << 7)


static size_t
locate_fragment_end (const char *str, int *err)
{
  const char *t = strchr(str, '}');

  if (t)
    return t - str + 1;

  fputs("fragment end error\n", stderr);
  *err |= NO_FR_END;
  return 0;
}

static const char *
get_data_name (const char *s, struct dfr *p)
{
  // пропустим разделители до `'`
  size_t pos1 = strspn(s, " \t");
  if (s[pos1] != '\'') {
    fprintf(stderr, "no name begin %zd <%c>\n", pos1, s[pos1]);
    p->str_error = NO_NAME_SQUOTE;
    return 0;
  }
  // пропустим символы имени (ожидаем найти `'`)
  size_t pos2 = strcspn(s + pos1 + 1, "{'[&]}");
  if (s[pos1 + pos2 + 1] != '\'') {
    fputs("no name end\n", stderr);
    p->str_error = NO_NAME_EQUOTE;
    return 0;
  }

  p->name = s + pos1 + 1;
  p->namelen = pos2;

  return s + pos1 + pos2 + 2;
}

// returns data fragment length or 0 (if no more in str)
size_t
get_data_fragment (const char *str, struct dfr *p)
{
  p->str_error = 0;
  p->fr_len = 0;
  // пропустим разделители до `{`
  p->fr_begin = strspn(str, " \t\n\r") + str;
  if (*(p->fr_begin) != '{') {
    if (*(p->fr_begin)) // неверный символ разделитель 
      p->str_error = NO_FR_BEGIN;
    return 0;           // конец данных в строке ?
  }

  const char *scont = get_data_name(p->fr_begin + 1, p);
  if (!scont)
    return locate_fragment_end(str, &p->str_error);

  char c = 0;
  int nchrs = 0,
      rc = sscanf(scont, " ; [ %d & %d ] ; [ %d & %d %c%n",
                  p->p1, p->p1 + 1, p->p2, p->p2 + 1, &c, &nchrs);
  if (rc != 5 || c != ']') {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid data pair(s) scanf = %d in: \"...", rc);
    while (*scont && *scont != '}')
      fputc(*scont++, stderr);
    fputs("...\"\n", stderr);
    p->str_error = INVALID_DATA;
  }

  size_t sz_ret = locate_fragment_end(scont + nchrs, &p->str_error);

  if (sz_ret) {
    p->fr_len = sz_ret + (scont + nchrs - p->fr_begin);
    return p->fr_len + (p->fr_begin[p->fr_len] != 0);
  }
  return 0;
}

static void
print_fr_str (struct dfr *p, int n)
{
  size_t l = p->fr_len;
  const char *s = p->fr_begin;
  
  l = p->namelen;
  s = p->name;

#if DEBUG
  printf("name: \"");
  while (l--)
    putchar(*s++);
  printf("\"  [%d %d] [%d %d]\n\n",
         p->p1[0], p->p1[1], p->p2[0], p->p2[1]);
#else
  printf("str%d -- ", n);
  while (l--)
    putchar(*s++);
  printf("  %d %d %d %d\n",
         p->p1[0], p->p1[1], p->p2[0], p->p2[1]);
#endif  
           
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *data[] = {" { 'Parametr1 2000' ; [ 5 & 2 ] ; [ 3 & 2 ] }{   'ParametrLoooooooong 2021';[10&5];[ 6 &4]}",
                  "{'Parametr 2000' ; [ 5&2 ] ; [ 3 & 4z ] }",
                  "{ 'Parametr 2000';[ 5 & 2 ];[ 3 &10 ] }"
  };

  int n = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]); i++) {
#if DEBUG  
    puts(data[i]);
#endif
    
    size_t l;
    struct dfr r = {0};
    for (char *str = data[i]; str && (l = get_data_fragment(str, &r)); str += l) {
      if (r.str_error)
        fprintf(stderr, "weak str_error %d\n", r.str_error);
      
      print_fr_str(&r, ++n);
    }

    if (r.str_error)
      printf("str_error %d <%s>\n", r.str_error, r.fr_begin);
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Как обычно, компилируем, запускаем и смотрим результат

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc ttt.c  -O3 -Wall
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
str1 -- Parametr1 2000  5 2 3 2
str2 -- ParametrLoooooooong 2021  10 5 6 4
invalid data pair(s) scanf = 5 in: "... ; [ 5&2 ] ; [ 3 & 4z ] ..."
weak str_error 128
str3 -- Parametr 2000  5 2 3 4
str4 -- Parametr 2000  5 2 3 10
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

***UPDATE***

Если снизить требования к допустимым символам-разделителям между фрагментами, открывающей фрагмент `{` и началом имени, символам составляющим имя и т.п., то код, конечно, можно немного сократить.

```
const char *
get_fr (const char *str, struct dfr *p)
{
  p->str_error = 0;
  p->fr_len = 0;
  const char *s = str, *t;
  if (!*s)
    return 0;
  
  if (p->fr_begin = strchr(str, '{')) {
    if (p->name = strchr(s = p->fr_begin + 1, '\'')) {
      p->name++;
      if (t = strchr(s = p->name, '\'')) {
        p->namelen = t - s;

        char c = 0;
        int nchrs = 0,
          rc = sscanf(t + 1, " ; [ %d & %d ] ; [ %d & %d %c%n",
                      p->p1, p->p1 + 1, p->p2, p->p2 + 1, &c, &nchrs);
        if (rc != 5 || c != ']') {
          fprintf(stderr, "invalid data pair(s) scanf = %d in: \"...", rc);
          s = t + 1;
          while (*t && *t != '}')
            fputc(*t++, stderr);
          fputs("...\"\n", stderr);
          p->str_error = INVALID_DATA;
          return *t ? t + 1 : t;
        }

        if (s = strchr(t + nchrs, '}'))  {// this is "good" return
          p->fr_len = s - p->fr_begin + 1;
          return s + 1;
        }
        
        p->str_error = NO_FR_END;
        p->fr_len = t + nchrs - p->fr_begin + 1;
        return t + nchrs;
      } else 
        p->str_error = NO_NAME_EQUOTE;
    } else
      p->str_error = NO_NAME_SQUOTE;
  } else {
    p->str_error = NO_FR_BEGIN;
    return 0;
  }

  if (s = strchr(str, '}')) {
    p->fr_len = s - p->fr_begin + 1;
    return s + 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Для разнообразия я изменил возвращаемый тип на указатель. В этом случае использование функции может выглядеть вот так:

```
for (const char *str = data[i], *t; t = get_fr(str, &r); str = t) {
  print_fr_str(&r, ++n);
}
```

P.S.
Если что-то непонятно или заинтересовало, спрашивайте.

Comment: а если `typedef` объявить для структуры? Или стиль какой-то нарушается?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, если нравится копаться в коде, выясняя, что именно стоит за `typedef`,  то объявляйте (многим настолько нравится, что и в своих книжках всем это советуют (видимо считая, что таким образом развивают абстрактное мышление))

Comment: @ avp, понятно, хотел ваше мнение узнать по этому поводу  :)

Comment: @ avp,  А если структура с большой буквы будет, тоже не подходит?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, пишите так как вам больше нравится, или так как ваша команда это нормально будет воспринимать.